# Parse Platform list all classes/tables

Tags: parse-platform

How do I get a list of all classes/tables that exist in an instance of [Parse Platform](https://parseplatform.org/)?

I looked around and can't find a way. Essentially I'm trying to do the same thing as Oracle query:
`select * from all_table` but for Parse Platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Parse Js SDK you can use `Parse.Schema.all()`. Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#schema